# Is it possible to simulate a continuos press in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript

The closest solution to a continuous key press that I know is just repeating a key press a certain number of times:

```
repeat 1000 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
end repeat
```

But that's now what I'm trying to do. I need to simulate a continuos press, which means that it's like if the user keeps holding down the 'c' button for a certain amount of time. Is it possible to do that in AppleScript?

**Edit** I'm trying this way:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down "c"
    delay 10
    key up "c"
end tell
```

Result: it keeps pressed "a" instead of "c". Why? I also have tried with the key code 8 (key down 8), with the same result.

Comment: Why do you need to press this key continuously?

Comment: Key down; delay; key up should do it

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried this way but it doesn't work. Give a look to my edit please.

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem to me. Rather than explaining what the larger picture is, OP is asking how to implement the solution they think will get them the next step closer. Or maybe you're just looking for a NO answer - AppleScript isn't designed for this type of task and gets interrupted quite often when the script is intended to hammer on the resources of the system.

Comment: I really need to continuously press a key. It's for playing a videogame in an easier way and avoid to always hold the key (and there's no way to change the key configuration).